# Redirecting HTTP and HTTPS requests to a temporary page - https:// is not redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect all HTTP and HTTPS requests to `https://example.com/coming-soon.html`.

Here is the last `.htaccess` file that I tried:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/coming-soon.html [L,R=302]

RewriteOptions inherit
Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

I'm interested in **always** redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, that seem to work already, but in the meantime I need a redirection of entire domain to `/coming-soon.html` since the site is not ready yet. With the `.htaccess` above, HTTPS requests are not redirect to `coming-soon.html`.

Before, I had this other `.htaccess` file in place:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.89$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !coming-soon.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coming-soon.html [R=302,L]

RewriteOptions inherit
Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

With this `.htaccess`, redirection is taking place and HTTPS works, but if i type `https://example.com`, it takes me to the root of the site file names in php.

I've read a lot of links but am literally either not understanding correctly or I'm doing something wrong. I'm aware of the `RewriteCond` for the IP it's not yet set for my IP as exception to the redirection. I can do without it the IP exception for time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect `http(s)://example.com/anything` to `https://example.com/coming-soon.html`, except for a given IP address, try these `.htaccess` directives:

```
# Tested on Debian 10 running Apache 2.4.38
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=192.168.001.001
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/coming-soon\.html$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/coming-soon.html [R,L]
```

In fact, only `https://example.com/coming-soon.html` will not be redirected; we do not want to start a loop.

Among the `.htaccess` directives that you posted, these lines:

> `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/coming-soon.html [L,R=302]`

do not produce the expected redirection of `https://example.com/anything` to `https://example.com/coming-soon.html` because `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` alone does not match HTTPS requests. The addition of `[OR]` and an alternate `RewriteCond` make `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` optional.

---

In the case where `/coming-soon.html` includes images that are grouped within an `/images` directory, the `.htaccess` directives can be:

```
# Tested on Debian 10 running Apache 2.4.38

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Except for a given IP address,
# and for '/coming-soon.html' itself
# and for files within '/images/',
# redirect all requests to '/coming-soon.html'.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=192.168.001.001
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/coming-soon\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/coming-soon.html [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, learnt something new.I needed to also add this as otherwise locally hosted images would be broken RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: @hihaho67, you're welcome. Do you mean the images that are inserted in the `/coming-soon.html` page? If yes, are these images grouped in a directory?

Comment: yes exactly. Coming soon shows a logo and a bg image, all of which are hosted under /images/bg.jpg for example. These are broken without adding the command from the previous comment. I'm presuming as a request it gets redirected/blocked to /coming-soon instead of the relative path? But am still noob with regards to htacess

Comment: @hihaho67, I extended my answer after your comment about images being used in `/coming-soon.html`.

Comment: You sir, deserve respect. :Bow